# jquery value in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have this json returned from my ajax call

```
 [
{message:"haha", type:"error"}, 
{message:"nice work", type:"success"},
{message:"closed.", type:"success"}
  ]
```

and I need to find out if any of the items are of the type error. Now I know I can loop through and figure it out but I wonder if if there is a function that I could tell me what i need to know

Comment: Do you only need to know *if* there's an error anywhere, or do you need to know which specific one?

Comment: Just so you know, that's not valid JSON. You need to enclose each "Key"(?) with quotations. So `{message: "haha", type: "error"}` would become `{"message": "haha", "type": "error"}`

Comment: Then before you parse the JSON, you could just do an `.indexOf()`. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to parsing the JSON, you could test the string for a match.

```
var json = '[{"message":"haha","type":"error"},{"message":"nice work","type":"success"},{"message":"closed.","type":"success"}]'

if( json.indexOf('"type":"error"') > -1 ) {
    // there was an error somewhere
}
```

If the json is a little loose with spaces around the keys/values, you could use a regular expression to test instead.

Comment: Our conversation on my answer totally aside:  This seems brittle.  As you mentioned with the possibility of spaces, `.indexOf` would probably cause confusion down the line when an errant space throws off the condition.  Rather than resorting to regex, why not just parse the JSON and then loop it?  After analyzing the structure of the JSON data, `message` probably contains the error message *anyway*, so the data will need to be parsed anyway.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I'd agree with all points. The only reason I posted this as a possible solution was that OP noted *"Now I know I can loop through and figure it out but..."*. Searching the string was the only solution I could think of that didn't involve an explicit loop. I assume there's a bit of processing to do on the data, and OP didn't want a separate loop just to look for an error.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to loop. You can do it with a straightforward loop, or use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) if you like.

**Off-topic**: Note that what you've quoted isn't [JSON](http://json.org). It's object literal notation. To be [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com), the key names would need to be in double quotes:

```
[
    {"message":"haha", "type":"error"}, 
    {"message":"nice work", "type":"success"},
    {"message":"closed.", "type":"success"}
]
```

Some "JSON" parsers (particularly those that are really JavaScript parsers in disguise) are lax and let you get away with it, but that's becoming less common.

Comment: I wouldn't call it off topic to point out the JSON syntax error.  in fact, I'd give you a +1.

Comment: I'd guess that OP is posting the data post-parsing. Technically your corrected code is still not actual JSON.

Comment: i just copied from data.toSource() but the actual jaon does have quotes but thank you for pointing that out anyhow

Comment: @patrick: In what way is my posted text not JSON? My read of http://json.org says it is, as does http://jsonlint.com.

Comment: Outer quotation marks and in javascript, escaping the newline characters. As posted, it's just Array and Object literals.

Comment: @patrick: No, you're confusing strings with markup. What's presented is JSON markup. If you put it in program source code, *then* you'd have to put it in quotation marks. But any other use of it (reading it from a file, retrieving it via XHR, etc., etc.) you don't. Also, any whitespace (not just sapces) is valid between tokens. JSON is just a markup syntax, like HTML. You don't require that everyone put HTML in quotes, do you? :-)

Comment: Yes, but how is it distinguished as such in your answer? I'm certain you've noticed that there's much confusion between JSON data and javascript objects/arrays. Take @Stephen's answer. With the inclusion of `var json = `, clearly it is source code, yet he seems to think (as is common) that simply quoting the property identifiers makes it JSON. If I'm being a little pedantic, it isn't without need in my opinion. I know you know the difference, but others looking at your code won't know.

Comment: @patrick: Note that absence of `var json =` in my answer. I think it *confuses*, rather than clarifies, the issue to constantly tell people to put their JSON in quotes. It only applies in very artificial situations. (And you're quite right that Stephen's answer uses array and object literal notation, not JSON; that's a completely different matter.)

Comment: Yes, the absence of `var json =` it is duly noted, and I note the same absence in the question, and yet in your answer you refer to it as object literal notation. I tend to think that because JSON is text data, and can only be parsed as such,  it's an important distinction to make.

Comment: @patrick: Right, but what else could what the OP posted be, as it clearly *isn't* JSON? C'mon, this is really getting silly. HTML is text data, too, and can only be parsed as such. But let's leave it there. @Stephen: LOL!

Comment: It could be the parsed result of what was originally JSON data. See the confusion? On one hand, you say it must be object literals, but on the other hand you say it's invalid JSON markup. With regard to HTML, I don't know of any data structure in javascript that could be confused with HTML markup.

Comment: @patrick: I'll say no more. We'll just have to agree to disagree. You think I'm making things more confusing, I think you are. Done.

Comment: I'll respect that. Thank you for the interesting conversation anyway. :o)

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = [
    { "message" : "haha",      "type" : "error"  }, 
    { "message" : "nice work", "type" : "success"},
    { "message" : "closed.",   "type" : "success"}
];

$.each(json, function(i, k) {
    if (k.type === "error") {
        // this is an error
        // `k.message` contains the expected message
        // `i` contains the index key of the array, in this case `0` 
    }
});
```

Note:  Although my example uses Array and Object literals to express the point (instead of *actual* JSON text), you should ensure that valid JSON keys are wrapped in quotation marks ¹.

<sub>1 for @patrick. :)</sub>

Comment: That still isn't JSON data. It's just Array and Object literals.

Comment: yeah...  included for clarity, captain pedant.

Comment: Correcting legitimate errors or points of confusion is not pedantry. You stated that valid JSON keys must be wrapped in quotation marks. Then you proceeded to wrap the keys as such, and reference the data in a variable called `json`. Either you erroneously believed that was JSON data, or you've added to the confusion of others.

Comment: @patrick: If you really want to get technical, [JSON is a text format](http://www.json.org/).  That means *your* accepted answer is also not JSON, it is a JavaScript string (not text... a scalar value.  Technically, a string literal.) stored in a variable.  Is it closer to correct?  I'll give you that.  But close only counts in horseshoes.

Comment: We both have a `json` variable. Which one will succeed with `JSON.parse( json )`? I can't figure out what you're trying to argue at this point.

Comment: Last time I checked, an object wasn't text.  I can't figure out what you're trying to argue at this point.

Comment: *"We both have a `json` variable. Which one will succeed with `JSON.parse( json )`?"* You really can't figure out what I'm trying to argue? Alright, I'll be blunt. Yours is not JSON. It will fail. Mine will succeed and be parsed into the proper data structures for the language.

Comment: @patrick we have reached an impasse; You are the obvious JSON police, and I'm the renegade.